# Freeze while downloading with libcurl C/C++

Tags: c, windows, sdl, libcurl, freeze

I'm working on software which downloads a file and shows transfer speed via an SDL window.
My problem is that when I launch a download, the window is immediately identified by windows as a crashed program. As soon as the download is completed, everything is okay.
My program didn't crash and I think that it's because it can't respond when it's downloading.
Any ideas how to solve that?

PS: example of code which 'crashes' when performed:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, valeurs->URL);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, downloadData);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Comment: Perhaps you can perform your download in a separate thread and  occasionally poll the download for progress?

Comment: How do you mean "identified by windows as a crashed program"?

Comment: @KristerAndersson I think he means the standard "application does not respond"-type behavior with the window changing color.

Comment: @Bart: I actually use a thread, the other part of the programm run code but still identified like crashed. By crashed, i mean the window changing color and if the user click inside, a window pop up for close the programm =<

Comment: BTW, curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, downloadData); run code in downloadData() several times/second and i receive datas generated by this function :|

Comment: After performed some tests, I've new fact. The issue is linked with SDL: my code without SDL work perfect but as soon as I add SDL, the freeze happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent those freeze, you need to put, in the main thread an event manager (SDL_PoolEvent + SDL_Delay to not overuse CPU)